# Image.onload function not triggering

Tags: javascript, html, image

```
ReferenceError: imageNoteTaker is not defined

layer.add(imageNoteTaker);
```

Above error is coming while trying to do simple tweening using kinetic.js. My project is trying to sync an audio with an animation. The function 'sync()' is called frequently  while playing audio. This function inturn calls function 'animation1()' when the audio reaches 4.85s. The code in that function is causing me problem.

Here while trying to execute the 'layer.add(imageNoteTaker);' line, the variable imageNoteTaker is not defined. But the code to define imageNoteTaker is present before it in image.onload() method. But control is not skipping this totally.

The error is occuring in the following part:

```
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src="images/note_taker.png";        
    imageObj.onload = function(){
        imageNoteTaker= new Kinetic.Image({
            x: stage.getWidth()/2.35,
            y: stage.getHeight()/1.5,
            width: 75*202/100,
            height:75*350/100,
            image: imageObj
        });
    }
    layer.add(imageNoteTaker);
    layer.draw();
```

This is my whole code:

```
//Variable Declaration
var audioId=document.getElementById("audioId");
var currentAnimation="none";



//Kinetic Library Setup
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'moving',
    width: 800,
    height: 545
}); 

//Layer Declaration
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();   
stage.add(layer);


//Function called 3-4 times in a second while playing audio
var sync=function(){
    var currentPosition = audioId.currentTime;
    console.log("direct from audio tag: "+currentPosition);
    currentPosition=currentPosition.toFixed(2);
    console.log("after rounding : "+currentPosition);
    switch(true){
        case rangeGenerator(5.85,currentPosition):
            console.log(currentAnimation + "is CurrentAnimation");
            if(currentAnimation!="animation1"){
                currentAnimation="animation1";
                animation1();
            }
            break;
        default:
            console.log("default");
    }
};




//Function used in sync() function to check a value is in particular range
var rangeGenerator=function(value,currentPosition){
    if(Math.abs(currentPosition-value)<.25){
        console.log(currentPosition+"dfd"+"value");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
};


//Function that triggers the first animation; NoteTaker
var animation1=function(){
    console.log("Animation1");
    //Image Note_Taker Initialisation
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src="images/note_taker.png";        
    imageObj.onload = function(){
        imageNoteTaker= new Kinetic.Image({
            x: stage.getWidth()/2.35,
            y: stage.getHeight()/1.5,
            width: 75*202/100,
            height:75*350/100,
            image: imageObj
        });
    }
    layer.add(imageNoteTaker);
    layer.draw(); 

    console.log("Tweening...");
    var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
        node: imageNoteTaker, 
        duration: 1,
        x: stage.getWidth()/2.35,
        y: stage.getHeight()/4.0
    });     

    tween.play();


};

//On window resize, resizing stage too.
window.onresize = function(event) {
    stage.setWidth((window.innerWidth / 100) * 80);  // 80% width again
};
```

How can i remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

An onload method is typically called when an Object has been loaded. Upon completion of loading a load event is fired. This event then triggers the method.

If it is so, the onload method should be skipped in the execution of your code when you call animation1 function. Therefore the variable is not defined.

I'd suggest to make the variable imageNoteTaker global inside the class - put it under the definition of currentAnimation - and call layer.add(...) only when the variable is set.

Comment: What did you mean by this sentence "put it under the definition of currentAnimation".

Comment: //Variable Declaration
var audioId=document.getElementById("audioId");
var currentAnimation="none";
var imageNoteTaker=null;

Comment: If i declare it global, then another error shows saying that imageNoteTaker is null.